# Can a tiny leak get worse?

Tags: plumbing, leak

I replaced my shower arm with one that has a universal 1/2" male end so I could install a Culligan water filter showerhead. I did a fair amount of research beforehand and made sure to teflon tape the ends in the direction I would be screwing so as not to unravel the teflon while screwing. On the outer end of the shower arm, there is a tiny leak that, after about 10 seconds, forms a single drop that falls from the head and then repeats after another 10 seconds. I have tightened it as much as I can, and it seems harmless, but I have no idea.

Will it get worse? And is there anyway to know if I am leaking on the other end, inside the wall?

Comment: It's leaking where the shower head attaches?  Is there a washer inside the part that attached to the pipe?  Can you include some photos?

Comment: actually, in disassembling and reassembling to get pictures, i appear to have resolved the leak!

Comment: If there's mineral in the water, minute thread leaks often are self-healing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it *could* get worse, but does it really matter? The leak is inside of your shower area and should not be a cause of huge concern.

That portion of pipe is normally not under pressure except when the shower valve(s) is opened, and then only subject to back-pressure created by the restriction of your shower head (unless you have installed one of those "shut-off" type devices upstream of your shower head; which I do not recommend using, BTW).

Your second question, **"is there anyway to know if I am leaking on the other end, inside the wall?"**, concerns me a bit. If you have reason to believe that the shower-arm thread connection inside the wall is anything less than perfect, you need to take action. Pull away or remove the trim flange (sometimes called an *escutcheon*) which covers the hole in the wall where the shower-arm passes through and inspect the threaded fitting with a flashlight. Chip away additional material from around the shower arm if necessary to get a good look (don't chip too much, make sure the trim flange will still cover the hole). You need to ensure 100% that there is no leak inside the wall.

Comment: Emphasis: ___if___ you have reason to believe the connection inside the wall has problems. That would be a very uncommon place for an issue to occur; it's almost certainly a soldered joint rather than a threaded connection.

Comment: @keshlam, I believe the OP is referring to the shower-arm connection at the wall, which is pretty much *always* threaded and cannot be seen from outside; bad place for a leak. That's why I do not like shower heads or other shower accessories that effect a positive shut-off, they pressurize this connection. Sadly, the thin-walled, cheap foreign chrome-plated brass shower arms commonly offered at "big-box" stores have made this connection a common suspect. I have seen them cracked and broken at the thread just from tightening a bit too much. +1 for *if* though, don't fix it if it ain't broke.

Comment: @jimmyfixit: good point' I'd forgotten that. Odd choice, unless there's an expectation that the arm will be replaced often.